# Popout every 60 sec - cmd

Tags: cmd

I want every 60 sec a messsage to pop out as an reminder

I tried

```
@echo off
:loop
msg * Some text
@ping -n 60 -w 1000 0.0.0.1 > NUL
goto loop

@echo off
:loop
msg * Some text
timeout /t 60
goto loop

@echo off
:loop
msg * Some text
ping -n 60 localhost >nul
goto loop
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
@echo off

set /a secs=60
set /a ms=%secs%*1000

:loop
echo Process will wait for %secs% seconds and then continue...
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w %ms% > nul
msg * done
goto loop
```

or to make a generic script that waits for x seconds call the below version with the # of secs as a param, for this you would do the msg and loop in your control script:

```
@echo off
rem call with # of seconds to wait

set /a secs=%1
set /a ms=%secs%*1000
echo Process will wait for %secs% seconds and then continue...
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w %ms% > nul
echo.
::msg * done
exit
```

added later

```
@echo off
rem call with # of seconds to wait

:loop
set /a secs=%1
set /a ms=%secs%*1000
echo Process will wait for %secs% seconds and then continue...
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w %ms% > nul
echo.
msg * done
goto loop
exit
```

Comment: This loops as expected on my pc.